# False access denied warnings on Drupal 7 logs

Tags: logging, drupal, warnings

I am getting access denied warnings in my log files which seem to be associated with valid and succesful actions by a logged in user.

They are showing as access denied on a node attributed to Ananoymous and an IP address that is different each time and not associated with the logged in user:

```
access denied   23/05/2021 - 19:40  user/55 Anonymous (not verified)    
access denied   23/05/2021 - 19:26  node/85 Anonymous (not verified)    
page not found  23/05/2021 - 19:24  forum/134   Anonymous (not verified)    
access denied   23/05/2021 - 19:23  user/329    Anonymous (not verified)
```

Occasionally I appear to get page not found in similar circumstances.  Apart from the warnings in the log it appears to be working for the user.

Any suggestions as to possible causes? it is Drupal 7.80 and I only use configured modules without any bespoke code.All are up to date.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Follow the next steps

1. Check from the next url that you have permission in your node type

https://your-domain.com/admin/people/permissions

2. Is the content published?
3. If it doesnt work, the problem could be in contrib modules, try to uninstall them until the functionality works again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you.

Thanks but there is no problem with the appropriate users viewing the content. I also suspected a possible issue before I added forums/advnaced forums. The forums have generated a lot more actiovity so make the 'problem' more obvious; I suspect them as false warnings because they seem to only happen around proper forum activity - the same minute and forum nodes; when there are no or ferw users the wqarnings are much more occasional.

It is an irritation rather than a problem at the moment.

Could anaonymous users of some form (robots?) be trying to piggy-back on users to try to gain access?